# Change kafka host and port when using Quarkus & SmallRye

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I am un unable to change Kafka host and port when I need to run it through docker-compose. I want to use same docker-compose to run my services and Kafka. so I need to change Kafka host.

I tried to provide the following environment variable with no luck :
mp.messaging.outgoing.my-channel.bootstrap.servers="Kafka:9092"

I used the same docker-compose in Quarkus/Kafka guides :
https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the guide assumes the code isn't running in a container

If your service is also running in a container, you'll need to set this on the Kafka container

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample docker-compose.yaml file.

```
version: '2'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.20.0-kafka-2.6.0
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"
    ]
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs

  kafka:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.20.0-kafka-2.6.0 
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties --override 
listeners=$${KAFKA_LISTENERS} --override 
advertised.listeners=$${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS} --override 
zookeeper.connect=$${KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT}"
    ]
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: "/tmp/logs"
      # Dev GQ - Laptop
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://172.23.240.1:9092
      # AWS Pre-Prod  
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://11.122.200.229:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

And here is a sample Quarkus application.properties file with kafka bootstrap server configured as advertised listeners in docker-compose.yaml. This is a native inside on another docker image.

```
# Configure the SmallRye Kafka connector
# Dev GQ - Laptop
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.bootstrap.servers=172.23.240.1:9092
# AWS Pre-Prod
#mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.bootstrap.servers=11.122.200.229:9092
quarkus.kafka.health.enabled=true

# Configure the Kafka sink (we write to it)
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.topic=prices
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer

# Configure the Kafka source (we read from it)
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.topic=prices
# ..... more codes
```